# Return table in stored procedure postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I want to return the whole table with *stored procedure* not *function*

my code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.test()

RETURN TABLE (
     id   numeric
   , test varchar
   ) AS  -- Results  -- remove this
$func$

BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT * 
    FROM public.test

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

but its not works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stored procedures aren't meant to return anything, use a function. And you don't need PL/pgSQL for that either:

```
create or replace FUNCTION public.test()
  returns TABLE (id   numeric, test varchar) 
AS
$func$
  SELECT * 
  FROM public.test;
$func$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```

As you return all columns of one table, you can also use `returns setof`

```
create or replace FUNCTION public.test()
  returns setof public.test
AS
$func$
  SELECT * 
  FROM public.test;
$func$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Then use it like a table:

```
select *
from test();
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I want CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  not create or replace FUNCTION.

Comment: @KrunalPandya: that's not how Postgres works. Procedures are **not** intended to return results sets. Use a function for that.

Comment: What is the particular reason why a procedure instead of a function?  A function is the correct way to do this. IMHO Two of the worst words in development:  "I want", three of worst words: "I don't want". Especially without a good well defined reason.

Comment: @Belayer: the reason is probably "Because we have always done it that way in SQL Server"

Comment: I've just started looking at postgres coming from a TSQL background and I wondered, if procedures aren't supposed to return results why not always use functions? (procedures seem almost like a trigger to me [in TSQL context])